# 'ngbd-modal-component' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement NgbModal into my code, but I keep getting the same error:
'ngbd-modal-component' is not a known element.

It's probably something stupid I forgot, but I'm breaking my head over this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Core.module

```
import { NgModule, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { NgbModule, NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NavComponent } from './components/nav/nav.component';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './shared/components/spinner/spinner.component';
import { LoggerService } from './services/logger.service';
import { throwIfAlreadyLoaded } from './guards/module-import.guard';
import { NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent } from './shared/components/config-modal/config-modal.components';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgSelectModule,
    NgbModalModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  entryComponents: [NgbdModalContent],
  exports: [NavComponent, FormsModule],
  declarations: [NavComponent, SpinnerComponent, NgbdModalComponent, NgbdModalContent],
  providers: [LoggerService]
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: CoreModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'CoreModule');
  }
}
```

Component

```
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class NgbdModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-component',
  templateUrl: 'src/lazy/modal-component.html'
})
export class NgbdModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'World';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to your exports in the core.module:

```
exports: [NavComponent, FormsModule, NgbModalModule],
```

EDIT

Sorry I didn't realize NgbdModalComponent was a custom component. Try exporting it instead of the module:

```
exports: [NavComponent, FormsModule, NgbdModalComponent],
```

Comment: Thought this didn't work, but I restarted my server and now it works. Thanks!